# How to change Icon colour when row is at top or bottom using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I've built my table through string html format in vb.net and getting data through databases into the table in form of rows and columns.

Rows are moving `Up and Down` using `jquery onclick function`,

**All I want is when a row is at top then the blue arrow become gray because It is not allowed to move above and same is for bottom.**

I can show you my table in this picture: 
[image]

Here is jquery onclick function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.HashirDown', function () {


var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');

parentRow.insertAfter(parentRow.next());

});

$(document).on('click', '.HashirUp', function () {

    var temp = $(".HashirUp").index(this);
    if ($(".HashirUp").index(this) > 0) {

    var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');

    parentRow.insertBefore(parentRow.prev());
}
else {
    return false;
}
});
```

Here is the StringHtml Format table :

```
 For i = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<tr>", StrHtml)
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td   colspan=""2"">{1}</td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Decsription"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td   colspan=""2"">{1}</td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Condition"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td  >{1}</td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Result_"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td  >{1}</td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Type_"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td >{1}</td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("PS_ID_Redirect"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td >{1}</td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("TPL_Discount"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td  >{1}</td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Hub_Redirect"))

        If i = 0 Then
            StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td class=""HashirUp""><img class=""btn_img"" src=""../icon/up.png""  title=""Can not move up, already first""/></td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Order_"))
        Else
            StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td class=""HashirUp""><img class=""btn_img "" src=""../icon/up.png""   title=""Move up the order""/></td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Order_"))
        End If
        If i = DT.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td class=""HashirDown""><img class=""btn_img"" src=""../icon/down.png""  title=""Can not move down, already last""/></td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Order_"))
        Else
            StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td class=""HashirDown""><img class=""btn_img "" src=""../icon/down.png""   title=""Move down the order""/></td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("Order_"))
        End If

        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td class=""edit up""><a href=""#"" onclick=""Get_Price_Key_IU('{1}');"">Edit</a></td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("PS_ID"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}<td class=""delete up""><a href=""#"" onclick=""Del_Price_Key('{1}');"">Delete</a></td>", StrHtml, DT.Rows(i).Item("PS_ID"))
        StrHtml = String.Format("{0}</tr>", StrHtml)

    Next
    StrHtml = String.Format("{0}</table>", StrHtml)
    Return StrHtml
```

Comment: On each arrow click, check it's direction, if up arrow is clicked, find the number of rows previous to it, if they are greater than one, the up arrow should be enabled else disable it. Similary, it goes with down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [filter property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)

```css
.gray {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c7757f497ba7c0bbe832d91989e935eb?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" alt="" width="32" height="32">
<br><br>
<img class="gray" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c7757f497ba7c0bbe832d91989e935eb?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" alt="" width="32" height="32">
```